# How can I cast an object as an interface which is a generic type constraint in Delphi

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-2010

I need to interact with series of .Net web services. There are currently about 150.
Since delphi 2010 uses Thttprio to achieve this, I am trying to create a generic Proxy on the client side that can be called to create the appropriate soap service client.
Does anyone have any idea how I can cast the httprio object to a generic interface type?

Thanks

Below is the proxy function I'm trying to use:

```
class function Web.Proxy<T>(svc: string): T;
var
  HTTPRIO : THTTPRIO;
begin
  HTTPRIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil);
  HTTPRIO.URL := GetServiceURL(svc);
  Result:= HTTPRIO as T; //<-- Fails with "operator not applicable to this operand type"
  // Result:= T(HTTPRIO); //<-- also fails, but with "invalid typecast"
end;
```

The idea is that I can call this with:

```
Web.Proxy<AutmobileServiceSoap>('svc.asmx').GetAutomobile(125);
```

The WSDL import has the AutmobileServiceSoap defined as follows:

```
AutmobileServiceSoap = interface(IInvokable)
```

And all the wsdl imports have a function that returns the httprio object cast in a similar manner:

```
function GetAutomobileServiceSoap(UseWSDL: Boolean; Addr: string; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO): AutomobileServiceSoap;
const
  defWSDL = 'http://localhost:8732/Cars.Server/Data/AutomobileService.asmx?WSDL';
  defURL  = 'http://localhost:8732/Cars.Server/Data/AutomobileService.asmx';
  defSvc  = 'AutomobileService';
  defPrt  = 'AutomobileServiceSoap12';
var
  RIO: THTTPRIO;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if (Addr = '') then
  begin
    if UseWSDL then
      Addr := defWSDL
    else
      Addr := defURL;
  end;
  if HTTPRIO = nil then
    RIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil)
  else
    RIO := HTTPRIO;
  try
    Result := (RIO as AutomobileServiceSoap);
    if UseWSDL then
    begin
      RIO.WSDLLocation := Addr;
      RIO.Service := defSvc;
      RIO.Port := defPrt;
    end else
      RIO.URL := Addr;
  finally
    if (Result = nil) and (HTTPRIO = nil) then
      RIO.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use RTTI to get the GUID of the interface

```
type
  Web = class
    class function Proxy<T: IInterface>(svc: string): T;
  end;

class function Web.Proxy<T>(svc: string): T;
var
  HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO;
  data: PTypeData;
begin
  HTTPRIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil);
  HTTPRIO.URL := GetServiceURL(svc);
  data := GetTypeData(TypeInfo(T));
  if ifHasGuid in data.IntfFlags then
  begin
    HTTPRIO.QueryInterface(data.Guid, Result);
  end;
end;
```

If you specify the IInterface constraint you can be sure that T is always an interface (otherwise you have to check the TypeKind of the TypeInfo also).

Comment: +1, In fact IInterface is needed for QueryInterface, or else IUnknown would be enough :)

Comment: @whosrdaddy Actually you don't need the constraint to be able to compile but with the constraint you are safe to only use it with interfaces which are the only types that make sense here. I think you can even get rid of the has guid check because otherwise it does not work with THTTPRio anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Since `T` can be anything you must make it clear to Delphi that `T` will be an interface.
Since all interfaces inherit from `IUnknown`, you can write this:

```
  Web = class
    class function Proxy<T  :IUnknown>(svc : string) : T;
  end;
```

Comment: Thanks, but With that change although casting with T(HttpRIO) now compiles, but I get an access violation when I call it.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Is it possible using rtti?

Comment: It seems you have your answer :)